# How to check if ClearType is enabled in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In my application I want to set the Consolas font on some textbox controls at runtime. As Consolas is a ClearType font and only does look good when ClearType is enabled, I want to check if ClearType is enabled.

Can I check if ClearType is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947.aspx), see this link for more info:

- [ClearType Antialiasing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183433.aspx) from MSDN

and a sample code:

```
Private Declare Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32" Alias
    "SystemParametersInfoA" (ByVal uAction As Integer, _
    ByVal uParam As Integer, ByRef lpvParam As Integer, _
    ByVal fuWinIni As Integer) As Boolean

Private Const SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE As Integer = &H200A
Private Const FE_FONTSMOOTHINGCLEARTYPE As Integer = 2

Private Function IsClearTypeEnabled() As Boolean
    Dim uiType As Integer = 0
    Return SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE, 0, uiType, 0)
    AndAlso uiType = FE_FONTSMOOTHINGCLEARTYPE
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [FontSmoothingType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.fontsmoothingtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation`

```
public static bool IsClearTypeEnabled
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return SystemInformation.FontSmoothingType == 2;
        }
        catch //NotSupportedException
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @Claudio B, you may also want to check the `SystemInformation.IsFontSmoothingEnabled`property, which checks if font smoothing is enabled. This is an independent setting from ClearType:

```
public static bool IsClearTypeEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return SystemInformation.IsFontSmoothingEnabled && 
             SystemInformation.FontSmoothingType == 2;
    }
```

, y